# Swift: IBoutlets are nil in Custom Cell

Tags: ios, swift, custom-cell

I can't figure out why this custom cell is not being output.

I have a custom cell set up in a storyboard (no nib). 
I have a text field and 2 labels which are nil when I try to access them in the custom cell class. I'm almost sure I have everything hooked up correctly, but still getting nil.

I've selected my table cell in the storyboard and set Custom Class to `TimesheetTableViewCell`
I've also control clicked on the table and set the datasource and delegate to be `TimesheetViewController`

**My custom cell class:**

```
import UIKit

class TimesheetTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var duration: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var taskName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var taskNotes: UILabel!

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init?(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    println("Cell's initialised")// I see this
    println(reuseIdentifier)// prints TimesheetCell
}


override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

func setCell(duration: String, taskName: String, taskNotes: String){
    println("setCell called")
    self.duration?.text = duration
    self.taskName?.text = taskName
    self.taskNotes?.text = taskNotes
}
```

**My controller:**

```
class TimesheetViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet var timesheetTable: UITableView!

var items = ["Item 1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.timesheetTable.registerClass(TimesheetTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TimesheetCell")

}
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TimesheetCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TimesheetTableViewCell
        println(items[indexPath.row]) // prints corresponding item
        println(cell.duration?.text) // prints nil
        cell.setCell(items[indexPath.row], taskName: items[indexPath.row], taskNotes: items[indexPath.row])
        return cell
}
```

Comment: instead of `self.timesheetTable.registerClass(...)`: use `self.timesheetTable.registerNib(...)`, maybe...?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
self.timesheetTable.registerClass(TimesheetTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TimesheetCell")
```

Delete it. That line says: "Do *not* get the cell from the storyboard." But you *do* want to get the cell from the storyboard.

(Make sure, however, that the cell's identifier is `"TimesheetCell"` in the storyboard, or you'll crash.)

Comment: Ok, that got my default cell data to show up. Thanks! I still can not seem to access the iboutlets though, any idea? trying to self.taskName?.text = "something" in cell.setCell has no effect because taskName is nil

Comment: Prove to me that the outlets from the cell to labels in the cell are really hooked up, please!

Comment: Haha! I would but I've already gone ahead and changed my code. I ended up starting again and creating a nib along with the custom cell class, then in my contoller viewdidload() I called this         self.timesheetTable.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TimesheetTableViewCell", bundle: nil)!, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TimesheetCell"). I appreciate your help matt, thank you.

Comment: Right, that's another way. But that doesn't really solve the problem. It should have worked just as well in the storyboard. You can get the cell from a nib and configure the outlets in the nib, or you can get the cell from the storyboard and configure the outlets in the storyboard. I have examples of both at my github site.

Comment: I'll check your examples, thanks matt. this was driving me batty

Comment: For a storyboard-instantiated and configured cell I think this is the one you want: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch08p407addCellSubviewsInStoryboard

Comment: Also it might help you to read the discussion in my book, which summarizes all the ways of customizing a cell: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_custom_cells

Comment: thanks for the info matt, you have a swift book in the works?

Comment: Really great examples @matt, have been stuck on this for a while. Thanks for great free swift material on Github

Comment: hi @matt
I know this is old. But instead of creating a separate cell file, I create a cell subclass inside the table view controller file. When I run the project, I got this error: fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented
Do you know why did I got that error?

Comment: @JozackOverFlow Yes I do. It's because your code says `fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")` - do a global search and you'll see it.

Comment: @matt Thanks matt, I figured it out, forgot to super.init(coder:) in the required method

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that you need to remove the line

```
self.timesheetTable.registerClass(TimesheetTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TimesheetCell")
```

from viewDidLoad().