# UITableViewCell IBOutlets are nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a very similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411140/swift-iboutlets-are-nil-in-custom-cell).

I have a custom UITableViewCell prototyped in the story board that contains an image view and a label. I control dragged the outlets and set my cell identifier name "BasicCell".

```
class newsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var image1: UIImageView!


    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func configure(text: String, image2: UIImage){
        label.text = text
        image1.image = image2
    }
}
```

and in my simplified UITableViewController I have:

```
class mainlistTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.registerClass(newsTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "BasicCell")
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "BasicCell";           
        let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! newsTableViewCell
        myCell.configure("12345", image2: UIImage(imageLiteral: "Default.png"))
        return myCell
    }
}
```

When I run like this, I get an error at the `func configure` that IBOutlet label does not exist.

When I remove the line: `self.tableView.registerClass(newsTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "BasicCell")` the program crashes at line: `let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! newsTableViewCell` with the following output:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9dbb61b360'
```

Any ideas on what can be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the storyboard select `UITableViewCell` prototype , in attributes inspector set "BasicCell" as identifier.

right click on UIImageView And UILabel in Cell and make sure there is no unLinked or old connection.

remove `self.tableView.registerClass(..)`

it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The error was indeed because of an old connection before I changed the name of the imageview. I deleted that connection and everything worked!!